# Iterating over CSV file to match items in another list

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to automate the filing of some scanned documents. These are identified by an object number which needs to be matched to a job name.

I have a list of extracted file names within a folder and a CSV file that contains around 50,000 records of object numbers and job numbers.
I can get a correct match for chosen job numbers with `== obj_num[0]` etc but I can't work out how to iterate through the list.

```
import glob,os,csv

items = glob.glob('*.pdf')
obj_num = [".".join(f.split(".")[:-1]) for f in items if os.path.isfile(f)]

job_id = []


with open('locations.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    field_names = ['jobid', 'ItemUniqueId', '###anotherfield', '###anotherfield2']
    for row in csv_reader:
            if row['ItemUniqueId'] == obj_num:
                job_id = row['jobid']
    print(job_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you build a lookup `dict` that you can use to directly find the `JobID` based on the associated `ItemID` (coming from the filename). Thus, you iterate once through the CSV file, and build the lookup:

```
lookup = {}
with open('locations.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    field_names = ['jobid', 'ItemUniqueId', '###anotherfield', '###anotherfield2']
    for row in csv_reader:
        lookup[row['ItemUniqueId']] = row['jobid']
```

Then, for each filename, you search the lookup for the `JobID` using the `ItemID` as key:

```
job_id = lookup.get(item_id) # returns None if not found
job_id = lookup[item_id]     # raises as KeyError if not found
```

You can also check if the `ItemID` exists in the lookup by using:

```
if item_id in lookup:
    # something something something
```

Also, you might want to take a look at `pathlib`, which is a built-in module providing you with high-level access to the filesystem. If I read your code correctly, you're trying to remove the extension from the filename, which `Path.stem()` does for you, e.g.:

```
from pathlib import Path

for pdf_file in Path('your path here').glob('*.pdf'):
    file_name_wo_suffix = pdf_file.stem
    job_id = lookup.get(file_name_wo_suffix)
```

Comment: thank you for the help! I've tried the above and I can't get it to work. I'm getting an error on the return line ("return" outside function")  but I'm going to have a think for a while and come back to it. My end aim is to append the job_id number to a directory and then move the relevant PDF to that folder.

Comment: sorry, the `return` shouldn't have been there. I modified the post to remove it.